# Problem on a subfield being dense in $\mathbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, field-theory

> Let $K$ be a subfield of $\mathbb C$ not contained in $\mathbb R$. Is $K$ always dense in $\mathbb C$?

I have studied to show a set $A$ is dense in $B$  we will have to show that for any element $x$ in $B$ there exists a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$.But dont know what should be my approach here?

Comment: @user26857 Yes, that was intentional since the poster was a little more elaborate there, and received two answers there. It is well-established that [timestamps are not a priority](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16418/29335) when marking duplicates. Regards

Answer (score 3):

It is true; here is an explicit proof.

We know that as $K$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, we must have $\mathbb{Q} \subset K$. As $K$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, there is some element $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha \in K$. So, in particular, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \subset K$, and it suffices to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

As a real vector space, $\mathbb{C}$ has basis $\{1,\alpha\}$. Thus any $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ can be written uniquely as $\lambda + \mu \alpha$ for some $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, an equivalent definition of 'dense' to the one you allude to above is that for every open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, we have $U \cap K \neq \emptyset$. By passing to a subset of $U$, we may assume that $U$ takes the form $U = \{\lambda + \mu \alpha: \lambda \in (a_1,b_2), \mu \in (b_1,b_2)\},$ with $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Then as $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we can pick $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a \in (a_1,a_2), b \in (b_1,b_2)$. Then $a + b\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\cap U$, so the intersection is non-empty and hence $K$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: thanx for your answer but how do you get such a form of $U$ with the restrictions on $\lambda$ and $\mu$

Comment: Alternative proofs have been given in the other place this question is asked, but to answer your question - you can take the set of open balls as a basis for the usual topology on $\mathbb{C}$. So we may as well assume that $U$ is some open ball of centre $A + B\alpha$ and radius $\varepsilon$. Then set $a_1 = A - \varepsilon/10$, $a_2 = A + \varepsilon/10$, $b_1 = B - \varepsilon/10,$ $b_2 = B+\varepsilon/10$. This box is contained inside $U$ (draw the picture!!). (I've used 10 as I didn't want to think exactly what value would force the square to be inside; ultimately, it doesn't matter).